# Big Outgoing traffic on windwos azure

Tags: azure, network-traffic

I have a vm on Windows Azure running centos6 as dev node, and have recently experiencing a huge increase in outgoing traffic.

VM was stopped and after started by 1 day it shows 236.63 GB on outgoing traffic, server not running any applications, only 1 landing page.

need help how to detect what causing the traffic and how to prevent it, since it's reflecting badly on my bill.

Comment: Check log file to find what happened on your server.

Comment: are you reporting / uploading error logs, activity logs etc onto some service/ database that is outside azure ?